# Div Frame moving between pages

Tags: html, css

I've got a website that isn't behaving!  I need the div tag centered and have messed with all sorts of options, but can't seem to get all of the pages to remain in the same place.  In the current upload the Products page move a few pixels from the rest of the pages.

Any help would be awesome!
Thanks!
James

http://www.pingdynamic.com/sites/slva/products.html

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the products page causes scrollbars to appear so all content shifts left to allow for scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks for the super helpful response and not being a douche about the question at hand!